# How to discover edge nodes on iOS

Tags: edgeengine

I'm looking to recreate the same setup on my iOS application as the [sample iOS app](https://github.com/edgeEngine/quickstart-ios). In the sample app, there is an API call http://{localhost}/{clientId}/example/v1/drives?type=nearby that returns a list of EdgeEngineNodes for the application to use.

Do I need to implement this on my microservice or is there a build in function call in edgeEngine?

Answer (score 0):

Issue: Making a call to edgeEngine local discovery services.

Cause: Getting a list of devices in edgeEngine clusters.

Remedy: Calling edgeEngine **localDevices** API from the deployed edge microservice. Alternatively calling the same API directly from the iOS application at the service link returned by the mimik client library.

```
curl -i -H 'Authorization: Bearer <edgeEngine access token>’ http://localhost:<$port-number>/<MCM.BASE_API_PATH>/localDevices
```

mimik edgeEngine client library for iOS provides an API that returns the current edgeEngine service link:

```
    /**
     Service link to the edgeEngine instance. For example when configuring microservices for deployment.
     
     - Returns: Service link to the edgeEngine instance.
     - Note: Once the service link has been established, it will never change.
     - Note: For example http://127.0.0.1:[port-number]
     - Warning: The port number is randomly generated when queried the first time, then stored for subsequent restarts and can never change again.
     */
    @objc public func edgeEngineServiceLink() -> String
```

Note: Please see a full example of how this can be implemented in your edge microservice here: https://developer.mimik.com/first-edge-microservice/#title6